# Tektro brake bleed block size?

Tags: mountain-bike, brakes, disc-brake, hydraulic-disc-brake

The bleed kit for my Tekro HDC 330 hydraulic brakes did not come with a bleed block. I've seen a 15mm ring spanner mentioned as a suitable alternative, but would prefer to make/buy the correct tool.

What size/thickness of block is needed?

Comment: What model of brake do you have?

Comment: Fwiw I've always just used a Shimano one held in place with a rubber band. They fit snug and that's all you really care about.

Comment: @CardMechanic Good point, I have edited the question to include this.

Comment: @NathanKnutson Thanks, if I do not get the answer I will try a Shimano one.

Comment: Get an old credit card, cut it up to pad shaped bits and superglue enough bits together to make the thickness you need.

Comment: @mattnz I'm trying to work out the thickness I need!

Comment: I've done a bit of digging, based on what brake pads fit. It turns out they are Shimano sizes, so have order the bleed block that goes with the Shimano brakes. Will update with an proper answer once I have tested it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This model of Tektro brake uses a Shimano M575/M505/M445 brake pad - so I ordered the Shimano bleed block for these brakes (p/n Y8FZ05000) which did the job.

Comment: Thank you for coming back and letting us know what worked.  Closure is important, and appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have a hydraulic piston press, and it's 3.7mm thick.  I don't know if that's a standard across the board or if it's just this one though.

Comment: Is that for pushing the pistons back in? Or preventing them coming out when the lever is pressed?

Comment: Come to think of it, it's probably for pushing them in.  So it would be wrong for your use.  Sorry, hydraulic disc is my weakness

Comment: No worries. I could do with one of those, rather than making do with a big screwdriver.

Comment: Would you mark an answer for this question please?  Just to get it out of the "unanswered" queue?  If the answers here don't answer it, please just post an answer yourself that does and mark that as the correct one.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder - I was waiting to measure the block before answering, but will edit the answer once I have measured the block.